# how to distinguish between web application or standalone app.?

Tags: java

Is there a way to distinguish inside particular method if it is running in a web application (eg whole applications is deployed on tomcat/web sphere etc) or as a standalone application?

Comment: What is it you want to distinguish FOR?

Comment: I'm dealing with a legacy code, the application can run standalone or under tomcat. And there is a thread which starts during initialization of the application. I can now when the web application already started or is going to shutdown. I wanted to get the picture. The problem is when it doesn't run standalone thread is throwing exception, during start/stop of the web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "NO". There is no guaranteed way to determine whether your code runs in some kind of app server/servlet container or standalone without relying on external information.

You could, however, specify a system property in one case and not the other and check for its existence:

```
java -Dstandalone.mode=true MyApplication
```

In your code:

```
if (Boolean.getBoolean("standalone.mode")) {
  // we're in standalone mode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see if any instance of `HttpServlet` shows up in the current stack trace. Although it is not fool-proof, it may meet your specific needs.

**Note:** I have not tried running this sample code. Exception handling has been left out.

```
public boolean isWebApplication() {
    Class<?> httpServletClass;
    try {
        httpServletClass = Class.forName("javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }

    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()

    for (StackTraceElement element : stackTrace) {
        Class<?> elementClass = Class.forName(element.getClassName());
        if (httpServletClass.isAssignableFrom(elementClass)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: "Not fool-proof" is an understatement. This will work for servlets but not filters / spawned threads or, in case of full EE container, beans.

Comment: As it stands, your sample code would require HttpServlet to be on your classpath, which is unlikely to be the case for business logic

Comment: @ChssPly76: That's why I said "it may meet your specific needs". :)

Comment: @simonn: Thanks for the catch! I have modified it accordingly! :)

Comment: @Adam - understood. However, I've seen many cases where "specific needs" evolve after having initially been met and then everything suddenly blows up :-) Your answer is perfectly valid by itself; I just don't think it's the _right_ answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you'd want to check this within some "generic" business logic code that is not compiled with any app server or J2EE APIs on the classpath, i.e. you can't access HttpServlet directly. In that case, I think doing a `Class.forName()` for a J2EE or app-server-sepcific class would be your best bet.  If it throws and exception, it's standalone, otherwise, maybe you're in an app server.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult because there isn't a whole lot that is "different" between the two aside from what it runs in.  You could attempt to call

```
org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo.getServerBuilt()
```

And if it fails, then you aren't running Tomcat.  I'm not familiar with web sphere, but I would imagine attempting to call a specific method for that would work as well.  It's definitely a dirty way to do things, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to test for the [JNDI system properties](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.3/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#LISTPROPS) (assuming those don't get set in standalone mode to a remote server - and even then you should be able to know the difference in values, such as the server not referring to a localhost).